# Automatically set owner of system created file

Tags: file-permissions, sftp, ubuntu-14.04, cms

So you know how CMS create files by themselves, well I can't find a fix to make those files automatically belong to the right group (the group for the SFTP users). Is there something I can do to prevent this, or should I setup a cron job or something similar?

Comment: You expect an answer when you don't tell use what CMS you are using?

Comment: @DavidPostill Well no matter what the CMS, it's the files that are created by it that matter. It's just that the FTP users can't modify the files because they've been created by the system. This happens with all the CMS

Comment: [Wrong ownership when SFTP files](//superuser.com/q/757244)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Not exactly that, but I had an idea: maybe I should try to assign the FTP users to www-data group. Would that pose a security risk though?

Comment: No idea. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

There is most likely no way to prevent this from happening in the future, but if you have the time to correct these problems yourself, you just go into the file's properties and change the owner of the file.